# Swift/Firebase - Check if user is logged in via Facebook & Google

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I use CurrentSession environment object to store user info. A user can login into the app via Google or Facebook. I wanna keep the user logged in even after the app is closed and opened again. So I was going to check provider specific objects/variables to perform these checks. Works well for FB but unfortunately **doesn't work for Google** (!)

So I login via Facebook or Google and close the app..

When I **launch** my app again the CurrentSession is initialised. I check if the user was already logged in and it works well for Facebook by performing **AccessToken.current != nil** check.

But once I do the same for the user logged in via Google, when i **relaunch** the application GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser is always nil ;(

How should I perform this check for Google user? I know i can use Auth.auth() but at this moment I am looking for the way to do that via GIDSignIn object..

```
import Combine
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class CurrentSession: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String? = nil

    init() {

        // check if user logged via Facebook
        if AccessToken.current != nil { <-- WORKS WELL FOR FACEBOOK

            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res,er) in

                if er != nil{
                    print((er?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return

                }
                print("email: \(String(describing: res?.user.email))")
                print("name: \(String(describing: res?.user.displayName))")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.userId = String(describing: res?.user.displayName)
                }
            }
        }

        // check if user logged via Google
        if let user = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser, let authentication = user.authentication { <<-- HERE (CHECK DOESN'T WORK AS I EXPECT)

                let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                               accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in

                    if err != nil {
                        print("\(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
                        return
                    }

                    print("email: \(String(describing: res?.user.email))")
                    print("name: \(String(describing: res?.user.displayName))")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.userId = String(describing: res?.user.displayName)
                    }

                }
        } else {
            print("No current user found")
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, make sure to `import FirebaseAuth`.

Then you'll may want to create some `enum`:

```swift
enum AuthProviders: String {
    case password
    case phone
    case facebook = "facebook.com"
    case google = "google.com"
    case apple = "apple.com"
}
```

Then perform this check to determine the current provider that used to sign-in:

```swift
if let providerId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData.first?.providerID,
    let provider = AuthProviders(rawValue: providerId){
    switch provider {
        case .password:
            // Signed-in with Firebase Password
        case .phone:
            // Signed-in with Firebase Phone
        case .google:
            // Signed-in with Google
        case .facebook:
            // Signed-in with Facebook
        case .apple:
            // Signed-in with Apple
    }
}
```

*if your app uses other provider(s), you may get its ProviderID from [FIRAuthProvider.m](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/FIRAuthProvider.m) and add it to the enum

*Note that anonymous sign-in `providerId`'s will be `nil` as of [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3450)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i found a solution.

Here's the code that makes these checks:

```
if let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance(), signIn.hasPreviousSignIn() {
          signIn.restorePreviousSignIn()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userId = String(describing: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.userID)
                print("userId = self.userId")
            }
        } else {
            print("ATTEMPT FAILED")
        }
}
```